# How do I use a shared embedding for one hot encoded data in csv?

Tags: tf.keras, categorical-data, keras-layer, embedding, one-hot-encoding

I have multiple one hot encoded columns in a csv file
[(my one hot encoded columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZqGb.png)

I had to one hot encode them manually because they were comma separated values in each cell as shown here [(the column that was one hot encoded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6lDx.png). How do I create one embedding using tensorflow.keras.layers.Embedding for all the columns?

What should be the input shape for that embedding? It would be helpful if I could get some example code.